# Brackets ${}, $(), $[] difference and usage in bash

Tags: bash

Bash contains different braces and they used differently. Could you please explain comprehensively what is difference between `${}`, `$()` and `$[]`?
Where they are used in bash? What is their main purpose?

Comment: The proposed duplicate doesn't really cover the use of the various brackets with the dollar sign, though. It's more about `[]`, `[[]]`, `{}`, and `()`, with `${}` thrown in.

Comment: I came here looking to learn what `$[ ]` is. This questions asks exactly that and the dupe does not answer it.

Answer (score 21):

The keyword is `shell expansion`! So i highly recommend you to read the section `Shell Expansions` in your bash reference manual.

You can access this section online [1].

The names of the following stated forms are:

- `${}` Parameter expansion
- `$()` Command substitution

the form `$[]` isn't actually stated in the manual so i wouldn't use it.

[1] http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

Comment: `$[]` is a deprecated syntax for arithmetic expansion. It is thoroughly replaced by `$(())`

Comment: For a reference on $[ ] being obsoleted over $(( )) --- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete