# can't store `date` command output to a variable in a bash script

Tags: bash

In the bash shell,

```
$ date +%Y%m%d%H%M
202208161535
```

So I put it in a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
dat=${date +%Y%m%d%H%M}
echo "dat=" ${dat}
```

But when I run it, I get

```
$ test.bash
./test.bash: line 2: ${date +%Y%m%d%H%M}: bad substitution
dat=
```

How should I do it?

**ADD**
I found

```
dat=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
```

works. But I'm curious how I can do it with `dat = ${data +%Y%m%d%H%M}`.

**ADD2**
This question arose because of the mistake, or rather from not knowing the difference of ( ) and { }. Those who cannot notice this difference cannot search with search pattern 'difference of ( ) and { } in bash'. So the referenced links 'supposed to have solution for this question' cannot be searchable by the people like me. So I think this question is worth being kept as is.

Comment: `dat="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)"`

Comment: @anubhava Ah, I see. I used { } instead of ( ) ! Thanks!

Comment: 1. No space before/after `=`; 2. Use `$()` not ${} to eval a command

Comment: @anubhava if you make your comment an answer, I'll pick it.

Comment: @ChanKim: Thanks, it is just a syntax issue. I may take credit for solving a programming/scripting problem but not this one :)

Comment: Some more information about usage of various brackets: [Brackets `${}`, `$()`, `$[]` difference and usage in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992711)

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
dat=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
echo "dat="${dat}
```

The above code is working code

Comment: Do not use backticks. Use `$(..)` instead. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete . Also this is not working code - the last line has unclosed backtick. Remember to check your scripts with shellcheck

Comment: Hi Raja, thanks but I knew how to use back ticks when I asked it. I wanted to know $( ) method.

Comment: You are needlessly quoting a static string which does not need quoting, and failing to quote a variable which might need quoting. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)