# Calling a function in bash

Tags: bash

I created a function to list filenames in a directory. I have to do this without using ls.

```
#!/bin/bash

function myfind(){
    local directory=$1
    echo "$(directory)"
    for file in "$(directory)"/*;
    do
        if [[ -d "${file}" ]];
        then
             myfind "$file"
        else
            echo "(basename "${file}")"
        fi
    done
}
```

when I try to call the function it just states command not found. If I try to make it an executable (which I know is most likely wrong) it won't perform anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW, leave out the `function` -- `function myfind() {` merges the legacy ksh syntax `function myfind {` and the POSIX sh syntax `myfind() {` in a way that's incompatible with _both_ legacy ksh and POSIX sh. See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: And `"$(directory)"` is trying to run `directory` as a command, which it isn't, so it's correct to be not found. You want `echo "$directory"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I suggest closing this question with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992711/brackets-difference-and-usage-in-bash). It seems more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your shell script is you attempt to reference the `$directory` variable using command substitution `$()` instead of variable referencing `$`.

Also, the program `basename` already sends its output to stdout so there is no need to send the output to `echo`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

myfind() {
    local directory=$1
    echo "$directory"
    for file in "$directory"/*;
    do
        if [[ -d "${file}" ]];
        then
            myfind "$file"
        else
            basename "${file}"
        fi
    done
}
```

edit: forgot to add and as Gordon Davisson suggested, do not use the `function` keyword, it is not needed in Bash.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up your shell expansions, specifically `${ }` and `$( )`. They look similar, but do completely different things, and it's important to use the right one for the job. `$( )` does command substitution -- it runs what's inside the `$( )` as a shell command, captures its output, and basically inserts it into the command line at that point. `${ }`, on the other hand, treats what's inside it as a variable or parameter name (maybe with some modifiers attached), and inserts *its* value.

So when you use `"$(directory)"`, the shell tries to run `directory` as a command. But it's not a command, it's a variable, so that fails and you get a "command not found" error. You want `"${directory}"` (or just `"$directory"`, since this is one of the simple cases where `{} is optional).

Also, in the line

```
echo "(basename "${file}")"
```

...there's no `$` before `(basename`, so it's not treated as any sort of expansion, just a plain string. You want `"$(basename...)"`, except that (as UnrealApex pointed out) the `echo` and the `"$( )"` are basically cancelling each other out, and you should just omit both. So just use:

```
basename "${file}"
```

One more recommendation: the `function` keyword is nonstandard and unnecessary. I recommend just starting function declarations like this:

myfind() {
...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will attempt to fix my mistakes and see if I can get it running.

Comment: Well said. I give kudos to wjandrea as he was the one who pointed out `basename` already prints to stdout.